# Custom Exception Handling On Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can make custom Exception Handling on objective C... Any useful tutorial please guide me...

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cocoa you may want to understand why Exception Happening and have to solve the situation more then Handling that..Any way you can use

```
@try
{ 
  //Your code
}

@catch(NSException* e) // or subclass of NSException
{

}
```

[Refer this too](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html)

Comment: It's important to know that the semantics of the exception handling on ObjC is different to some other languages, such as C#, and great care must be taken to ensure that all objects are released properly.  I suggest either using GC, or using autorelease pools extensively. (Or both!)

Answer (score 4):

try/catch really should be avoided in all but the most extreme cases.  Apple have a great API for handling situations where known errors will occur by usually including an `NSError` parameter in the message invocation or delegate callback.  try/catch are not the usual mechanism for error handling but are used in extreme situations where you will usually abort your app anyway.  I would encourage you to rethink your application design and use the standard means of error handling before resorting to try/catch.

Comment: +1. I think it's particularly tempting for Java/C# developers to get started down the wrong path with this stuff.