# How to Handle SIGKILL,SIGABRT, Signal-0 exceptions through Exception Handling in iPhone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception

I have to catch the exception when `SIGKILL`, `SIGABRT`, `Signal-0` exceptions are raised.

Please Suggest how to handle the above Signals through Exception handling.

Can you please suggest me any sample code to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

developers with java and C# background are bound to go for exception handling in iOS. Apple has some really good API's to solve the known errors but the program should be made exception free(which i know is difficult). Sigabrt usually occurs when u over release a object and SIGKILL usually occurs when the systems kills your app due to lack of memory. So, i suggest you to read [the memory management guide by apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) . Also, you can go through [this link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1230-exception-handling-xcode-obj-c.html) and [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932198/custom-exception-handling-on-objective-c) . Apple has a class defined for [exception handling - NSException](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: SIGKILL is issued by the OS when the user changes OS-wide privacy settings. Memory management cannot avoid this scenario. I wonder if anyone has found an acceptable way to recover gracefully from this. In my own case, the app is frozen and needs a hard reset from the task manager!

Comment: To clarify my comment above — it appears that the app is only frozen when run from Xcode. If I untether it from Xcode, I get an acceptably graceful reboot behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can catch most of the unhandled exceptions by registering an NSUncaughtExceptionHandler in your app delegate.

Similarly you can trap most of the signals using [sigaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sigaction.2.html%23//apple_ref/doc/man/2/sigaction) or [signal](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/signal.3.html%23//apple_ref/doc/man/3/signal)

As you can see in both above links, you can not catch signals of type SIGKILL and SIGSTOP.

try analyzing your code for any possible reasons that cause these signals.

Comment: Links are broken.