# Catch crashes/exceptions only in my library, ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports

I am writing my own library. I want to catch crashes in my library. Library spawns several threads, writes to database, connects to remote servers etc.

My question: IS THERE A POSSIBILITY TO CATCH CRASHES THAT CAUSED ONLY BY MY LIBRARY?

**UPDATE 1:**

@try/@catch will only handle exceptions that are within method calls

```
@try {
do smth

//do async task in database

//start sending data to remote server


}
@catch {

}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I want to catch NSExceptions, EX_BAD_ACCESS and, if possible SIGABRT, SIGKILL, low memory etc.

Comment: Have you looked at `@try` / `@catch`?

Comment: When you say crashes, do you mean SIBABRT or something else?

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339801/how-to-handle-sigkill-sigabrt-signal-0-exceptions-through-exception-handling-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible per library, especially since libraries on iOS will be statically linked into the actual apps. Crashes happen per app process, there is no way to limit a crash reporting library to a subset of an apps code.

Your only option is to test your code as good as possible so that it doesn't have bugs that can cause a crash. Use instruments, static analyzer, write tests.